# SwiftUI Accessibility VoiceOver Focus Issue

Tags: ios, swiftui, accessibility, voiceover

I have one button on a screen and on tap of that button i am opening one modal (view). But after closing that view accessibility VoiceOver focus goes to top left element on the screen. I want that focus to stay on the same button after closing that view.

Comment: When you need to programmatically move the focus to a specific element, you can use Accessibility Focus State property wrapper and the accessibility Focused view modifier. This gives you the ability to set the focus of the app programmatically.

Comment: @amey rane, have you got any solution for this

Comment: Have you found any solution yet?  I am facing similar issue I'm swiftUI. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77934167/accessibilityviewismodal-in-swiftui