# accessibilityViewIsModal in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, accessibility, swiftui-navigationview, uiaccessibility

I've used `accessibilityViewIsModal - true` in UIKit where I need to shift accessibility focus from one view to another subview. How to use accessibilityViewIsModal in swiftUI?

I've tried following techniques to shift accessibility focus from one view to another subview.

- UIAccessibility.post(notification: .screenChanged, argument: "New Screen appear")

Result: Accessibility focus didn't change

- accessibilityViewIsModal = true

Result: Compile time error: Cannot find 'accessibilityViewIsModal' in scope

```
if showSelectPolicyView {
                SelectPolicyView(input: $inputData, showSelectPolicyView: $showSelectPolicyView)
                    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                    .clipped()
                    .zIndex(1)
                    .background(Color.gray)
                    .onAppear {
                        accessibilityViewIsModal = true
                    }.onDisappear() {
                        accessibilityViewIsModal = true
                    }
            }
```

Where and how to use accessibilityViewIsModal in `swiftUI` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`isModal`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/accessibilitytraits/ismodal) is one of the [accessibility traits](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/accessibilitytraits) you can add to a view, using [`accessibilityAddTraits`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/accessibilityaddtraits(_:)).

> Use this trait to restrict which accessibility elements an assistive technology can navigate. When a modal accessibility element is visible, sibling accessibility elements that are not modal are ignored.

That sounds exactly like what the documentation for `accessibilityViewIsModal` says.

Usage:

```
SomeView()
    .accessibilityAddTraits(.isModal)
```